# MongoDB full text search with haskell driver

Tags: mongodb, haskell, mongodb-query

Is there a possibility to use the full text search of mongoDB with the haskell driver?

I found the 'runCommand' in the haskell API, but it expects a Document as parameter. That's fine for all the other commands that mongodb can run, but the syntax for a text command is: 
    `db.collection.runCommand( "text", {search : "something"})`

So I don't know how I'll get the "text" as first parameter in front of the Document.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `text`-command can be written in another structure:

```
{ text: your_collection
, search: your_text
, filter: your_filter
, limit: your_limit
, project: your_projection
}
```

I had my suspicion, since all "runCommand"-action have the same structure. So I tried to apply that structure to the text-command - but without success. Then I remembered that `aggregate` has another structure too and tried that, but that didn't work either. Finally, I found the answer in a [google group entry of the Java driver](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/mongodb-user/7jWUbunUcFQ).