# mongodb via Haskell: How to enable text search

Tags: mongodb, haskell

How can I write the following mongodb query in Haskell?

```
db.quotes.runCommand( "text", { search: "tomorrow",
                            filter: { speaker : "macbeth" } } )
```

[This is the mongodb context](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/search-for-text/), and [this is the Haskell documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mongoDB-1.4.1.1/docs/Database-MongoDB-Query.html#t:Command).

**UPDATE**

I needed to run `mongod` with this command:

```
mongod --setParameter textSearchEnabled=true
```

and I also need to create indexes on the collections I want to search. I tried creating an index, but it didn't work. Here's my new question: [mongodb via Haskell: creating a text-search index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778815/mongodb-via-haskell-creating-a-text-search-index)

The code below isn't relevant to my new question, but I'll keep it here because it's how I constructed the query.

```
              mDoc <- run pipe dbName $ runCommand
                ["text" =: (docTypeToText docType),
                  "search" =: (unwords keywords),
                    "filter" =: (selector $ selection query)]
              case mDoc of
                Left failure -> do putStrLn $ show failure
                                   return []
                Right doc -> let Array results = valueAt "results" doc
                                 ds = [d | Doc d <- results]
                             in return ds
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [*document form*](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/use-database-commands/) of the command, see for example [`findAndModify`](https://github.com/selectel/mongoDB-haskell/blob/master/Database/MongoDB/Query.hs#L449). Simplifying @ichistmeinname's answer:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
search col term filter = runCommand [ "text"   =: col
                                    , "search" =: term
                                    , "filter" =: filter
                                    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked with MongoDB in a recent project and we used `runCommand` in connection with MongoDB's "text"-search mechanism. You just have to rebuild the JSON-structure with labels and corresponding values. In order to simplify the usage of `Text`-fields, the languages extension `OverloadedStrings` comes in handy.

A simple definition can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17729863/mongodb-full-text-search-with-haskell-driver/17731634#17731634) and the following code shows an example with "real" code.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
createTextCommand aCollection aTextQuery aFilter =
  runCommand command
 where
 command :: Command
 command =
   let text     = [textLabel   =: aCollection]
       search   = [searchLabel =: aTextQuery]
       filter'  = [filterLabel =: aFilter]
   in text ++ search ++ filter'
 filterLabel :: Label
 filterLabel = "filter"
 searchLabel :: Label
 searchLabel = "search"
 textLabel :: Label
 textLabel = "text"
```

The only "tricky" part is the `text`-field, since there's no label in the MongoDB-version that you quoted, but when you digg deeper, you'll find a version with a corresponding `text`-label as I quoted in my other post.