# mongodb via Haskell: creating a text-search index

Tags: mongodb, haskell

In order to search items in a mongo database by text, I need to create an index, as per the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/#create-text-index).

The code below creates this index:

```
index is Index {iColl = "note", iKey = [ text: 1], iName = "text_1", iUnique = False, iDropDups = False}
```

Why does the code give this error?

```
*** Exception: expected "results" in [ ok: 0.0, errmsg: "no text index for: db.note"]
```

**UPDATE**
I get the same error with the following updated code. What I changed is I now use `createIndex`.

```
         let order = [(fieldToText TextField) =: (1 :: Int32)]
              docIndex =  index (docTypeToText docType) order
          actionResult <- run pipe dbName $ createIndex docIndex
          case actionResult of
            Left failure -> do putStrLn $ show failure
                               return []
            Right () -> do
              putStrLn $ "index is " ++ show docIndex
              run pipe dbName $ ensureIndex docIndex
              mDoc <- run pipe dbName $ runCommand
                [pack "text" =: (docTypeToText docType),
                  pack "search" =: (pack $ unwords keywords),
                    pack "filter" =: (selector $ selection query)]
              case mDoc of
                Left failure -> do putStrLn $ show failure
                                   return []
                Right doc -> let Array results = valueAt (pack "results") doc
                                 ds = [d | Doc d <- results]
                             in return ds
```

**UPDATE** See comment below.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is: at the time Haskell driver was developed, MongoDB simply didn't support full-text indexing. So, it's impossible to create a `"text"` index with the current version of the driver.

**Update 1**: on second thought, you can probably create a `"text"` index upserting a document into `"system.indexes"`, like it's [done](https://github.com/selectel/mongoDB-haskell/blob/master/Database/MongoDB/Admin.hs#L129) in the driver.

**Update 2**: using `createIndex` won't help, because MongoDB [doesn't allow](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mongoDB-1.4.4/docs/Database-MongoDB-Admin.html#v%3aIndex) passing `"text"` as `iKey`. Here's an approach which seems to be working:

```
createTextIndex :: Collection -> String -> [Label] -> Action IO ()
createTextIndex col name keys = do
    db <- thisDatabase
    let doc = [ "ns"   =: db <.> col
              , "key"  =: [key =: ("text" :: String) | key <- keys]
              , "name" =: name
              ]
    insert_ "system.indexes" doc

search :: Collection -> String -> Document -> Action IO Document
search col term filter = runCommand [ "text"   =: col
                                    , "search" =: term
                                    , "filter" =: filter
                                    ]

main :: IO ()
main = do
    pipe <- runIOE $ connect host
    res  <- access pipe master "test" $ do
        createTextIndex "foo" "foo-index" ["bar"]
        search "foo" "some-keyword" []
    print res
  where
    host = Host "localhost" $ UnixSocket "/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock"
```

Comment: Do you know what this exception might be referring to? The `text` field is contained in the `obj` field. `*** Exception: expected "text" in [ score: 0.75, obj: [ _id: 52befd9e88458526ad000000, created: 2013-12-28 16:34:38.598 UTC, text: "Test note"]]` There are three places I use the literal "text", and when I change each of them to "obj.text", the error remains the same, except when I change the "text" in the text search command, in which case the error is `no such cmd: obj.text`. The other two places I changed "text" are the `doc` key and value in `createTextIndex`.

Comment: You should be using [`!?`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bson-0.2.3/docs/Data-Bson.html) operator to fetch nested fields, i. e. `doc !? "obj.text".

Comment: Where should I use this operator?